# when I run rails console in netbeans6.8(Ruby on Rails) then getting error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, netbeans6.8

when I run rails console in netbeans6.8(Ruby on Rails) then getting following error ?

'irb.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

what I need to do for this ?

Comment: Do script/console and IRB both load up when you try to run them from the OS command line?

Comment: Are you using JRuby or a native ruby executable?

Comment: I am using ruby executable not jruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows (I assume so because of irb.bat) you might want try to add the path to your Ruby installation into the Windows PATH environment variable.

Comment: yes I am using windows with ruby executable and I want to know how that windows path variable set ? please help me

Comment: For XP check out this link: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm